# Is it possible to adjust transaction fee amount in MultiBit Classic?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, multibit

I have a few transactions I made with MultiBit Classic 0.5.17 stuck in the unconfirmed land for days now. They all have a transaction fee of 0.0001BTC as that is the only way my version of MultiBit sends payments. I do not see a way to adjust the transaction fee. Is there a way to adjust a transaction fee in MultiBit Classic 0.5.17? If not, what do I do with coins stuck in unconfirmed transactions? What do I do with coins in my MultiBit Classic wallet? If there is no way to adjust the fee, how can I move them out of there with any hope the transaction will get confirmed?

Comment: There should be a slider to adjust the fees in multibit classic?

Comment: Can you export your private keys or sign raw transactions?

Comment: Recover your private keys: https://github.com/Multibit-Legacy/read-multibit-wallet-file

Answer (score 1):

It's been a little while and I have not gotten an answer here, but I figured it out myself and would like to post the answer to my own question here so it can help someone in the future.

The answer is NO, you can not adjust transaction fee amount in MultiBit Classic. It is only possible to send bitcoin with 0.0001btc transaction fee. This is outdated software and was hard coded to that amount.

What I did to deal with that is I imported my private keys from MultiBit Classic into Electrum, which not only is able to adjust the transaction fee, but also makes pretty good suggestions as to what the fee should be at the moment based on the data it collects from the network.

To export the keys you need to make them visible and that is not secure unless you are in a safe environment of your home, etc. After importing the keys to Electrum I was able to access that wallet and spend the coin to other places, which was my plan to begin with. You can always destroy the files with plain text keys by electronically shredding them (deleting does not destroy files beyond recovery). This is what I did.

Hope that helps someone in this situation in the future.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, you can help Bitcoin.SE by marking your own answer as accepted, that way the question does not remain "unanswered".

Answer (score 0):

Last time I did that with Multibit Classic, I waited for approx. 1 month before it hits the recipient wallet.  You just have to wait I guess.